# MySQL SELECT .... INTO OUTFILE not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have used the following code to backup a MySQL table:

```
$query = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mytableDB.txt' FROM mytable";
```

It does not appear to be working.

The following error checking code was used:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result)
    echo 'Database was successfully backed up';
else
    echo 'Not backed up';
```

but the documentation was not clear as to whether or not a return value is generated.

The message 'Not backed up' was echoed.

The database is accessed via WampServer on a Windows machine.

The manual located at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

does not appear to cover this issue.

Has anybody come across this problem & found a solution while using WampServer?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the database user has **FILE** permission.

```
GRANT FILE ON db.* TO user;
```

A quote from the manual you posted:

> The file is created on the server host, so you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax.

Comment: Thanks for that. All my other interrogations of the database work so this would not be the issue.

Comment: Sounds like the right answer. Why don't you at least try it @havelly. Basically he is saying your db user doesn't have permission to write to an actual file on the filesystem. That's what you're granting

Comment: Thanks for that. Gave the following a try: mysql_query("GRANT FILE ON *. * TO 'user_name'@'localhost'"); to no avail.

Comment: You need to have GRANT privileges to grant. Check for a web admin through your hosting account that let's you create and manage databases and users.